# Octave convert dataframe column of datetime strings to secs

Tags: matlab, dataframe, octave, strptime, mktime

Using Octave I have created a dataframe as the following;

```
>> df=dataframe("example.csv")
df = dataframe with 10 rows and 3 columns
Src: example.csv
_1                         X1     X2      X3
Nr                       char double  double
 1 2016-11-01 11:35:33.285127   1000 1205531
 2 2016-11-01 11:35:54.666606   2000 1205531
 3 2016-11-01 11:37:17.775407   3000 1205531
 4 2016-11-01 11:37:47.436518   4000 1205531
 5 2016-11-01 11:38:16.246998   5000 1205531
 6 2016-11-01 11:38:38.371844   6000 1205531
 7 2016-11-01 11:38:59.806459   7000 1205531
 8 2016-11-01 11:39:20.543602   8000 1205531
 9 2016-11-01 11:39:47.920399   9000 1205531
10 2016-11-01 11:41:24.370811  10000 1205531
```

I am looking to convert column X1 to seconds-since-the epoch (or a similar sequential measure of time, total seconds since 'the beginning of time' would also be fine)

I can get this to work with a single element (I'm assuming the ans is correct);

```
>> mktime(strptime(df.array(1,1),"%Y-%m-%e %T"))
ans =    1.4780e+09
```

But I'm not having much luck trying to convert the whole column; I have tried various permutations along the lines of;

```
>> mktime(strptime(df(:,1),"%Y-%m-%e %T"))
error: wrong type argument 'class'
error: strptime: argument STR must be a string


>> mktime(strptime(df(:,1).array(1,1),"%Y-%m-%e %T"))
error: Invalid call to numel.  Correct usage is:-- Overloaded Function:  numel (A)
error: called from
    numel at line 33 column 7


>> mktime(strptime(df(:,1).array(),"%Y-%m-%e %T"))
error: Invalid call to numel.  Correct usage is:-- Overloaded Function:  numel (A)
error: called from
    numel at line 33 column 7


>> mktime(strptime(df.array(:,1),"%Y-%m-%e %T"))
ans =    1.4780e+09
```

I am looking for an expression that will let me do an assignment like;

```
df(:,1)=expression()
```

Comment: Can you please create a complete example which creates a dataframe object and fills some values?

Comment: Hi Andy, I've updated the question to clarify, and added in specific data as an example.  -  So far hunting around I think I have discovered strptime simply will not work in this way, and I will need to use a foor-loop to iterate over the column elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
format long   #to see the differences     
x = cellfun (@(x) mktime (strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%e %T")),
             cellstr (df.array(:,1)))
x =

   1477996533
   1477996554
   1477996637
   1477996667
   1477996696
   1477996718
   1477996739
   1477996760
   1477996787
   1477996884
```

Comment: Hi Andy, this looks great but I'm still having trouble setting the first column of the dataframe to these values, or constructing a new dataframe with this as the first and columns 2:end of the original dataframe. Frustrating!  Ive tried df(:,1)=new_col  (TYPE error)  dataframe(new_col,df(:,2:end))  (use CAT instead error) .. and I cant get cat or horzcat to work; - cat(1,new_col,df(:,2:end)) (different num cols error)  ; cat(2,new_col,df(:,2:end)) (out of bound error) ...